# Unexpected behaviour of OCMock expect iOS Unit test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

I have a method with an implementation as follows:

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonTapped:(id)sender
{

    void (^SuccessBlock)(id, NSDictionary*) = ^(id response, NSDictionary* headers) {

    };
    void (^ErrorBlock)(id, NSDictionary*, id) = ^(NSError* error, NSDictionary* headers, id response) {


    };
   [ClassName deleteWebService:@"www.google.com"
                                           data:nil
                               withSuccessBlock:SuccessBlock
                                 withErrorBlock:ErrorBlock];
}
```

For which I have a test case as follows:

```
- (void)testLoginButtonTapped
{
    id mockClassObj = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[ClassName class]];

    void (^SuccessBlock)(id, NSDictionary*) = ^(id response, NSDictionary* headers) {

    };
    void (^ErrorBlock)(id, NSDictionary*, id) = ^(NSError* error, NSDictionary* headers, id response) {

    };

    [[mockClassObj expect] deleteWebService:@"www.google.com"
                                        data:nil
                            withSuccessBlock:SuccessBlock
                              withErrorBlock:ErrorBlock]; //code 1



    [[mockClassObj expect] putWebService:@"www.google.com"
                                     data:nil
                         withSuccessBlock:SuccessBlock
                           withErrorBlock:ErrorBlock]; //code 2

// putWebService is the another method of the same class

[mockObj loginButtonTapped:[OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[UIButton class]]];
        [mockObj verify];
    }
```

Both code 1 and code 2 are giving "Test Succeeded", code 1 is obvious but I can't understand why it is happening for code 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the *expect-run-verify* approach (see http://ocmock.org/reference/#strict-mocks-and-expectations), and you are setting expectations on `mockClassObject` but you never call `verify` on `mockClassObj`. This means the expectations in code 1 and code 2 are never verified and therefore the test doesn't fail.